# unable to insert extra space at first line of paragraph in RDLC report

Tags: .net, report, rdlc

I am working in project where I am using Microsoft reports (RDLC) for reporting. I am able to use html for formatting text in report by setting MarkupType=HTML, but one thing is there that I am unable to achieve.

My client wants that first line of every paragraph should start with some extra space, preferably a TAB. Like this:

```
      This is first line of the paragraph, and 
this is the second line of the same paragraph.
these are few more line of the same paragraph.
You might have noticed that the first line 
starts with some space, while others donot!!
```

I've googled a lot, and found that chr(32) do not solve the problem either. and & nbsp; gave a compile time error that "entity nbsp is not defined"

I've really appreciate if anyone could show me a possible way(preferably a solution!) for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue recently, using an expression worked for me:

```
="     This is first line of the paragraph, and" & System.Environment.NewLine &  "this is the second line of the same paragraph."
```